How to get local time in a Blazor WASM app
I would like to get in my Blazor WASM app the time in the client computer (as displayed in the taskbar in Windows 11), which seems like it should be straightforward.  However, I am getting a time that's +5 hours from my East Coast time, which seems to be UTC time.  I have read a bunch of posts about this issue nut none have provided a solution that seems to work, including using DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime() which compiles and executes without providing the local time. I would think this is a very common need.  Can you help me out?

Are you sure this is on Wasm?

Because <span>@DateTime.Now</span> should be all you need. If not, there is some setting in Program.cs or in your Browser that is wrong.

DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime() is contradictionary. Post an actual [mre], a few lines shouldbe enough. Make sure it exposes the problem.

Henk: My app is definitely Wasm.  I tried to convert it to PWA after creating it and think there may be something amiss with that.  I tried to replicate the problem in a small demo app, but it works as expected.  So there is some problem in my main app.  I checked Program.cs and my Chrome Settings, but didn't see anything that would lead to this problem.   I will be looking at the PWA issue in the next week or so.  Perhaps that's the source of the problem.  Anyway, thanks for your help.

PWA is unlikely to interfere with this. Your other comments hint at CurrentCulture vs CurrentUICulture but there is not much to go on.

Thanks for your continued thoughts, Henk.  Did a search for Culture.  Nothing jumped out.  At this point, I’m at a loss for what else to investigate.  Obviously a problem in my specific app.

I found a way around the problem, but don't really understand the unintended consequences, if any.  In my project file, I changed both  and  from false to true.  My app is unquestionably US-targeted, so maybe there is no downside.  Still don't understand why the local Windows 11 time isn't returned with these set to false.

Just discovered an unintended consequence.  The $ displays as some character I've never seen.  Back to square 1.

I've just tested this:
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<div class="bg-dark text-white m-2 p-2">
    <pre>Time: @_timeNow</pre>
    <pre>Local Time: @_localTimeNow</pre>
    <pre>UTC: @_utcTimeNow</pre>
</div>

@code {
    private DateTimeOffset _timeNow => DateTimeOffset.Now;
    private DateTimeOffset _localTimeNow => DateTimeOffset.Now.LocalDateTime;
    private DateTimeOffset _utcTimeNow => DateTimeOffset.Now.UtcDateTime;
}

And this is what I get:
My computer is set to Eastern Time Zone.


Thanks for the thoughts, which made me see that my question wasn't clear,  I need to get the DateTime in my c# code.   MrC, your 3 alternatives work as html in my app but not in my c# code (I still get +5 hours from all 3).  I also changed my Windows timezone Setting from Auto to Eastern and got the same result.  Henk, I suspect you are right, that there is some setting driving this, but I looked at both Program.cs and Chrome's Settings and couldn't see anything suspicious.   I'd appreciate any other thoughts.

Sorry, my last comment was not accurate.  MrC's code works in a demo app I created, but not in the one I'm focused on.

"I need to get the DateTime in my c# code."  ??? That's what my demo does, the time is in the C# code and converted though ToString by the Renderer to render it in html.  In what context, Service/Component/Utility do you want the time?

Don't know what I was thinking with the "in my c# code" comment.   I am trying to get the date & time in a static calss for a file (Excel) download triggered by the user hitting a button.  I'm putting that info in a cell of the spreadsheet and in the file name.  I originally used DateTime x = DateTime.Now and have since tried all the other variations.  Since it works in my demo app but not my primary one, there must be something in the latter that's causing the problem as Henk observed.
